# How to read .docx file using F#

Tags: f#

How can I read a .docx file using F#. If I use

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText("D:/test.docx")
```

It is returning me some garbage output with beep sounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a F# snippet that may give you a jump-start. It successfully extracts all text contents of a Word2010-created `.docx` file as a string of concatenated lines:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.IO.Packaging
open System.Xml

let getDocxContent (path: string) =
    use package = Package.Open(path, FileMode.Open)
    let stream = package.GetPart(new Uri("/word/document.xml", UriKind.Relative)).GetStream()
    stream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore
    let xmlDoc = new XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.Load(stream)
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.InnerText

printfn "%s" (getDocxContent @"..\..\test.docx")
```

In order to make it working do not forget to reference `WindowsBase.dll` in your VS project.

Comment: Thumb up for an elegant solution. Could switch to XDocument nowadays though. Framework 1.1 is closing in on 9 years old and Linq's XDom is obviously more functional.

Answer (score 1):

.docx files follow [Open Packaging Convention](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Convention) specifications. At the lowest level, they are .ZIP files. To read it programmatically, see example here:

[A New Standard For Packaging Your Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163372.aspx)

[Packages and Parts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2007/12/11/packages-and-parts.aspx)

Using F#, it's the same story, you'll have to use classes in the [System.IO.Packaging Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) from Microsoft.

Also on the linked page is the Microsoft tool that you can use to decompile the office 2007 files. The decompiled code can be quite lengthy even for simple documents though so be warned. There is a big learning curve associated with OpenXML SDK. I'm finding it quite difficult to use.

Answer (score 1):

`System.IO.File.ReadAllText` has type of `string -> string`.

Because a .docx file is a binary file, it's probable that some of the chars in the strings have the bell character. Rather than `ReadAllText`, look into [Word automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), the [Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx), or the [OpenXML](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) APIs

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have found docX here http://docx.codeplex.com/. But I don't know how to use this in F#. It will be very helpful if you can provide me some code on this.. And Very happy new year :-) Have a great year ahead

Comment: Not to mention that docx files are no compressed by default.